# Use a .rvmrc file from a Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, thor

## Backgound

A little background to this question first: Ruby on Rails has some security issues as of late. So we need to update the Rails version on our projects. If you have a few, that gets old fast if you do it by hand... So I figured I can create a Thor task for this.

## Question

This now works great! BUT! I need to respect the .rvmrc file for each project while installing the new versions of rails. I want this script to be OpenSourced soon, but I want to tacle the problem of not respecting the .rvmrc file first.

So what I need is a way of using the right RVM ruby version/gemset when I change to a directory to update the Rails version.

How is the way for this to be done? Can it be done from the Ruby script in a way so that it works on Mac and Linux, regardless of Shell (found a answer with zsh support, but what about all the other shells out there?)

Quick Example code:

```
#Scan the base directory down for Gemfiles
gem_files = File.join("**", "Gemfile")
Dir.glob(gem_files){|gemfile|
  project_folder = File.dirname(gemfile)
  puts "Found Gemfile in #{project_folder}"
  Dir.chdir(project_folder) do
    #TODO: Respect/load the rvmrc file in this directory
    update_gem_file(project_folder) #example
    run 'bundle update rails' #<--- needs to be done in the RVM gemset
  end
}
```

Just to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

### Link to the script on the githubs

[The github repo for my script -- Work in Progress!](https://github.com/davidakachaos/scan_and_up_rails)

Comment: Don't link to your code, provide a stripped/minimal version of it and append it to your question. The link will break eventually, and that will make your question of little or no value to others who are looking for a similar answer in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this project https://github.com/versapay/bundler-auto-update it basically:

> Attempt to update every single gem of your Gemfile to its latest patch, minor then major release. Runs a test command to ensure the update succeeded

As for RVM use this simple code:

```
#Scan the base directory down for Gemfiles
gem_files = File.join("**", "Gemfile")
Dir.glob(gem_files){|gemfile|
  project_folder = File.dirname(gemfile)
  puts "Found Gemfile in #{project_folder}"
  run "rvm in #{project_folder} do bundle-auto-update -c rake spec"
}
```

You can find more details on scripting with RVM on https://rvm.io

Answer (score 0):

Blindly upgrading Rails is not a good idea. At least run your test suite to ensure nothing breaks. After that you still want to do some QA on the app to make sure you didn't break all the things.

Then, How do you know that the current branch you're updating is actually the main develop branch? Don't you want to create a 'hotfix' branch and apply it to your production *and* development branches?

But, let's say you *did* manage to upgrade all your apps, they are still not deployed to production.

Comment: Like you say, blindly upgrading Rails may not be for everyone, just as it is NOT to deploy them automatically! That would be even worse (what if it does break?) imho. I will take up your suggestion to create a branch and perform the update there, just to be save.